# Getting column value from an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get each column values of merchant number using SQL and setting it to get from another class, tried below code which sends all the merchant number in single array but I need to set merchant number one by one.

```
 public String getData(List data) {
    data = new ArrayList();
    try {
        Connection con = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select merchant.T9F16_COD_CONVENZ" +
            "    , merchant.ID_ESRC" +
            "    , company.RAC_CM_RAGSOC" +
            "    , store.RAGIONE_SOCIALE" +
            "    , acquirer.DESCRIZIONE" +
            "      from KCA merchant);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String MerchantNumber = rs.getString("merchant.T9F16_COD_CONVENZ");

                data.add(MerchantNumber);
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return String.valueOf(data);
}
public String  getMerchantNumber() {
    return getData(this.MerchantNumber);
}
public void setMerchantNumber(List merchantNumber) {
    MerchantNumber = merchantNumber;
}
```

Now its sending as single array MerchantNumber: [1,2, 3, 4, 4]

But Expected is

MerchantNumber:1

MerchantNumber:2

MerchantNumber:3...

please share if there is a way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not really understanding the problem, could you please explain more

Comment: Your code looks like it is violating a lot of OOP principles.More clarification on the problem would help, but why don't you create an object which has the property ID, and add that to your ArrayList instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "ID:1 ID:2 ID:3" ? A variable and you change it's value ? Then I don't see the utility. A group of variable having different value ? Then your ArrayList does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I get the question completely, but to print the ArrayList to the console in the desired form you could first declare your ArrayList with the type String

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then after fetching the data from sql, just loop over the ArrayList to get the desired output:

```
    int i = 1;
    for(String dataStr : data) {
        System.out.println("MerchantNr."+ i + ": " + dataStr );
        i++;
    }
```

As for your call of String.valueOf() is simply returning a String represantation of your ArrayList. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)